# Accelerator data analysis once per second

Tags: java, android, timestamp, accelerator

I am working on an Android App to analyse the range of the accelerator per second. 
Is it a good idea to use the timestamp on the parameter "event"? 
I don't really know how to handle time in this situation.

Comment: What do you mean by using timestamp on the event? Do exemplify

Comment: using event in this method onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)

Comment: I know what event you are refering to. I am asking how to do you want to use the timestamp on the parameter? Because the SensorEvent already has a timestamp field you can use.

Comment: i thought i would get the time,when the method is called by using event.timestamp.

Comment: Yes. I don't think there is there is another way of getting an event's time coordinates.